# VBA: Setting a variable as a range based on cell addess

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub findReplace()
Dim myArray As Variant, rng As Range, str As Variant, cAdd2 As Range


myArray = Array("è", "é", "ë", "ê", "í", "?", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "ö", "à", "ã", "á", "Á", "ä", "ü", "â", "ø", "š", "??", ">", "<", "+", "*", "^", "ß", "ç", "å", "æ", ".", ";", "#", ":", "'", "-", "@", "Ã", "¨", "É", "Ô", "[", "]", "Ó", "Ñ", "(", ")", "Ö")

Set rng = Workbooks("User").Sheets("Result").Range("B2:B10")


For Each cell In rng
    cAdd = cell.Address
    Set cAdd2 = Range(cell.Address)
    For Each str In myArray
        If InStr(cell, str) Then
            cAdd2.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=Substitute(" & cAdd & ", " & str & ",""_"")"   -->**# This is where I get my error**
        Else
            cAdd2.Offset(, 1) = "=(" & cAdd & ")"
        End If
    Next str
Next cell


End Sub
```

What I want to be able to do is go through a range of cells, replace any characters that are in my array in that cell with an underscore in the cell next to it, and if there is no special characters, then just copy it over.

I believe the problem is with the cell.Address function, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you believe the problem is with that line?  What is it doing that is wrong?

Comment: It's not storing the actual address of the cell as a range. When I look at the value in the variable, it's actually the string that's in that cell

Comment: `cAdd2.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=Substitute(" & cAdd & ", " & str & ",""_"")"` on this line I get an "Application defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Change `" & str & "` to `""" & str & """`

Comment: It will show you the contents of the Range. However, you don't need to do what you're doing you could just use `Set cAdd2 = cell`

Comment: Also the logic of the function is off; if you have two special characters, only one would end up being replaced as the changes aren't additive

Comment: @Flephal You are definitely right and that's exactly what happened.Tom's answer below fixed it as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you give this a try. Will also allow for replacements of more then one character

```
Sub findReplace()
    Dim myArray As Variant, rng As Range, str As Variant
    Dim Form As String

    myArray = Array("è", "é", "ë", "ê", "í", "?", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "ö", "à", "ã", "á", "Á", "ä", "ü", "â", "ø", "š", "??", ">", "<", "+", "*", "^", "ß", "ç", "å", "æ", ".", ";", "#", ":", "'", "-", "@", "Ã", "¨", "É", "Ô", "[", "]", "Ó", "Ñ", "(", ")", "Ö")

    Set rng = Workbooks("User").Sheets("Result").Range("B2:B10")

    For Each cell In rng
        Form = "=(" & cell.Address & ")"

        For Each str In myArray
            If Not str = vbNullString Then
                If InStr(cell, str) Then
                    If Len(Form) > 0 Then
                        Form = Replace(Form, cell.Address, "Substitute(" & cell.Address & ", """ & str & """,""_"")")  ' -->**# This is where I get my error**
                    Else
                        Form = "=Substitute(" & cell.Address & ", """ & str & """,""_"")"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next str
        cell.Offset(, 1).Formula = Form
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly and fixed another issue I was having! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The error with that line is in my comments but this will be quicker, as it only has one loop and will replace every special character and not just the last found as @Flephal stated:

```
Sub findReplace()
Dim myArray As Variant, rng As Range, str As Variant


myArray = Array("è", "é", "ë", "ê", "í", "?", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "ö", "à", "ã", "á", "Á", "ä", "ü", "â", "ø", "š", "??", ">", "<", "+", "*", "^", "ß", "ç", "å", "æ", ".", ";", "#", ":", "'", "-", "@", "Ã", "¨", "É", "Ô", "[", "]", "Ó", "Ñ", "(", ")", "Ö")

Set rng = Workbooks("User").Sheets("Result").Range("B2:B10")

rng.Offset(, 1).Value = rng.Value
For Each str In myArray
    rng.Offset(, 1).Replace str, "_"
Next str

End Sub
```

---

Test:

```
Sub findReplace()
Dim myArray As Variant, rng As Range, str As Variant


myArray = Array("E", "S", "!", ")")
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B10")

rng.Offset(, 1).Value = rng.Value
For Each str In myArray
    rng.Offset(, 1).Replace str, "_"
Next str

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This will only replace any number of letters with one underscore

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks for your help! Is there a reason why I have to put three quotes around the array variable, but not other ones? Is this just a vba rule?

Comment: No, it will replace each one with the `_`  if the string has multiple it will replace each, one at a time.  And it will do the whole range at once for each letter.

Comment: It didn't in my test - a string of "éañbó" is left as "_"

Comment: Not on mine, you sure you did not end up with five `_` @Tom

Comment: Just the one I'm afraid. Also, with that string I should end up with `_a_b_`

Comment: @Tom Then there is something odd about your version. As you can see in my example above it works for me. And it will be quicker then two loops and a formula.